# UnsatisfiedLinkError in Samsung 4.4.2 devices

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, samsung-mobile

I'm keep on getting unsatisfied link error issue only in samsung 4.4.2 devices only.
The following is crash report from Google play dev console,i searched lot but cant find any solution for the following issue.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider.checkFipsMode:()Z
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider.checkFipsMode(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.getDefaultCipherSuites(NativeCrypto.java:797)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.init(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:198)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:186)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper.java:35)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:1005)
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:961)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:411)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:343)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
```

Comment: Off the cuff, it feels like a bug in Samsung's Android builds. What exactly are you doing in your code that eventually triggers this trace?

Comment: @CommonsWare m just calling my backend web service,above issue never appeared at the time of developing or debugging,only happening to my app users

Comment: also same thing running without any issue in other android version samsung devices

Comment: @immutable did you ever find out any more about this?  Seeing it here also with a couple of Samsung devices running 4.4.2

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly nope,Samsung have fixed above bug in their 4.4.4,but few devices doesn't get update..